# How to animate size parameter of ffmpeg zoompan filter?

Tags: ffmpeg

How is it possible to dynamically evaluate the `s` (output image size) parameter of ffmpeg [zoompan](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zoompan) filter on each frame?

The parameter expectes its value in "WxH" format i.e. "1920x1080". 
How to substitute an expression that would update the size as a function of, say, frame number?

Couldn't find a way to concatenate strings.

For a single number parameter I can do smth like `y='(out_h-in_h)/2'`, but how to take two expressions and join them with an "x" string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zoompan size parameter cannot be animated. It has to be a fixed numeral size of the form WxH, or a [size label](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Video-size) like hd1080.

Comment: Thank You again, Gyan!
I was hoping to achieve less than 100% zoom without padding by tweaking output size )